# Byte order of multiple fields in one BLE characteristic

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

on bluetooth.org I saw that one BLE characteristic can have multiple field. I now searched for a while but did not get an answer about the byte order.

For example this characteristic:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gatt.service_changed.xml

It has two fields. Is "Start of Affected Attribute Handle Range" the higher 16 bit or the lower?

Regards
Maz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GATT fields are always (or at least *should* always be) little-endian. This is discussed in the [Bluetooth Core Spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/archived-specifications).

From v4.2 of the spec, Vol 3, Part G (which covers GATT), page 523:

> 2.4 Profile Fundamentals
>
> ...
>
> • Multi-octet fields within the GATT Profile shall be sent least significant octet first (little endian).

Be very careful reading this spec because there *are* pieces that are in network order (big-endian), but GATT attributes are always supposed to be in little-endian.

(The only reason I a say "*should* always be," is that the one rule of bluetooth devices is that you will always find some device in the field that breaks the rules.... But the spec is clear.)

Comment: Thank you, but what does this mean for the above mentioned example? Byte order is clear now, but Is in the above example START or END more significant?

Comment: The first uint16 will the the start, and the second uint16 will the end. Fields come in the order listed; it's not about higher or lower there. Read the first 16 bits; that's the first field. The second 16 bits are the second field. Etc.

Comment: Well, Reading the value und Android or iOS will just return a 32 bit field. So I understand that the upper 16 bit are the start field.

Comment: On iOS, CBCharacteristic.value is a Data. So you should expect value[..<2] to be the first field, and value[2..<4] to be the second field. Calling the first two octets of a Data "upper" or "lower" is probably more confusing than helpful. "The first two octets" doesn't require an endian interpretation. (You wouldn't call the first element of an array the "upper element" or the "lower element.")

Comment: If I'm looking at the same quote in the spec the full version is "Multi-octet fields within the attribute protocol shall be sent least significant octet first (little endian) with the exception of the Attribute Value field. The endian-ness of the Attribute Value field is defined by a higher layer specification." I'm not sure what "high layer specification" means but that seems to indicate the endianness may not necessarily be little, or am I off here?

Comment: The "higher layer specification" refers to things like services (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/blood-pressure-service-1-1-1/ as an example) which may define the format of values. You always need to consult the documentation for the specific service you're using. But absent that, integers are little-endian in BLE.